# im having this errors when making an Ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, server, ionic5

I have been a lot of time trying to create my project, but, Im having a lot of errors. I fix some ones but, when I thought everything was okay, IT WASN'T. Im learning this ionic and app development stuff and I didn't thoght "oh, maybe any video on youtube shows aaaaall that" it looked easy!

Okay, this it's the error after putting the

```
ionic start appname sidemenu
```

I choosed angular, then it last a few minutes in do all their stuff, and then, when i write

```
ionic serve
```

(the first thigs were okay but then this:)

```
 Build at: 2022-11-16T20:03:58.075Z - Hash: 87f644733fcc69d9 - Time: 32811ms
[ng]
[ng] Error: src/app/folder/folder.page.ts:10:10 - error TS2564: Property 'folder' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
[ng]
[ng] 10   public folder: string;
[ng]             ~~~~~~
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] Error: src/app/folder/folder.page.ts:15:5 - error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
[ng]   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
[ng]
[ng] 15     this.folder = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
[ng]        ~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] × Failed to compile.
```

And the server said "cannot get" with the window name like "error"

can someone iluminate me with their knowledge?(and sorry for my english XD)

Comment: Please add your package.json. I suspect you are using Angular 14+ with an older version of Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to run the command `ionic build` before running `ionic serve`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tsconfig.json file and in `compilerOptions`, turn off `strictPropertyInitialization` and `strictNullChecks`, like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    ...
}
```